# distance between two points on different direction

Tags: distance, direction

I want to measure the distance between two points on the horizon and vertical axis. Is any function on GIS can achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  You've left a lot of details out of this question, to the point that it can't be answered.  Every GIS package has a way to measure distances; in fact, most probably have more than one way, plus programming interfaces to enable others.  Please edit the question to specify the exact GIS software you intend to use, what you have tried, and what difficulty you have encountered.

Comment: Are you trying to do what my answer assumes or are the two points located on the same plane? Similar answer exists either you have to calculate the angle of the line and then do a triangle solution, or create a 3rd point at the so the east-west and north-south lines can be calculated separately.

Answer (score 1):

Note: many GIS distance calculators only calculate 2D distances either on the ellipsoid surface or a planar surface.

Subtract the first point's elevation (z) from the second point's and take the absolute value. That's your vertical distance.

Create a third point that has the elevation of point 1 but the xy (or lat-lon) coordinates of point 2.

Run a distance calculator on point 1 and point 3 to get the horizontal distance.